# Is there a name for a ring with no additive inverses (like the non-negative real numbers)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology

Is there a name for an algebraic structure that abstracts from the non-negative part of a linear number system (for instance, the non-negative integers, or the non-negative reals)? In other words, is there a name for a ring with no additive inverses (or, more precisely, an algebraic structure determined by the ring axioms minus the axiom that stipulates additive inverses)?

Comment: Yes: *semiring*.

Comment: Or (by virtue of a joke that I like even though it isn't very good) "rig". (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring).

Comment: Double semi-group?